# Build an API for Multiple

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm building an API using WebAPI that will be accessed via AJAX calls. However, the API controller will need more than just one `POST` method. I understand I can specify `{action}` in my routing, but because I've seen that this is not recommended - am I using the right tool? So 2 questions:

1. Is Web API the best tool for this, or is there something else I should be using?
2. Why should I not use more than one `POST` method in a `WebApiController`? Is including `{action}` in my routing a good enough solution to this problem?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have multiple `POST` methods in WebApi. However, this is not possible, if you are building af REST API. But that's up to you and your requirements. So, just don't do REST. You can also combine REST, with other POST methods. That will work as well

Comment: WebApi follows the REST pattern, so the idea is that each controller acts on a single entity. You can easily put more posts in the same controller, but just make sure that it is to do with that entity.

Comment: You don't have to follow Restful guidelines, so put as many Posts as you want.  I've worked on plenty of non-restful Web APIs, especially ones that were converted from WCF and .asmx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1. Is Web API the best tool for this, or is there something else I should be using?*

I think WebAPI is a fine choice for you, regardless of whether you have one or many POST calls per controller.

*2. Why should I not use more than one POST method in a WebApiController?*

To remain RESTFul you'll want a controller per entity type. Without getting too deep into details, a POST against a specific type of entity should be the 'ADD entity' call, and why would you have more than one of those?  Having said that, you don't have to be fully RESTFul... if your requirements suite a multi-POST model then go for it, you can always refactor later if necessary.

*...Is including {action} in my routing a good enough solution to this problem?*

Again, if your goal is to be RESTFul then this isn't a great practice.  However, if you have needs that are best achieved using action routings then go for it.  REST is not the only model.